# @Autowired not working in spring batch custom writer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

```
    @Nullable
    @Autowired(required = true)
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends HashMap<String, Object>> items) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("inside product writer");
        for (HashMap<String, Object> hashMap : items) {
            categoryService.uploadDesktopDataModule(hashMap);
        }
    }
```

================================================================

My logic is there in another class to store data in the JPARepository.
 I am getting `null` value for the category service field.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `@Autowired` required defaults to `true` 2. How are you getting the object of the class shared ?

Comment: 1. ok 2. i can explain you.

Comment: @Service
public class ProductWriter implements ItemWriter<HashMap<String, Object>> {
 write method overriden here 

}

Comment: Please attach the whole source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will throw a

> NullPointerException

in the writer class when it tries to access the service auto-wired `CategoryService`, not because there is anything wrong with the wiring of the Service but because I instantiated `Writer()` manually with

```
Writer writer = new Writer()
```

`@Service`, `@Repository`, and `@Controller` are all specializations of `@Component`, so any to auto-wire needs to be annotated with one of them or `@Component`.

And need to instantiated as @Autowired Writer writer in job.